# Compare two XMLNodes in C (libxml library)

Tags: c, xml, xmlnode, nsxmlnode

I'm parsing some xml files in C using [libxml library](http://www.xmlsoft.org/docs.html). I want to compare two xmlnodes to see whether they contain the same data or not. Is there any function available to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [libxml API docs](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html) seem reasonable and suggest that [xmlBufGetNodeContent](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlBufGetNodeContent) and [xmlBufContent](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlBufContent) might do what you want.

```
xmlNode node1, node2;
......
xmlBuf buf;
xmlChar* content1 = NULL;
xmlChar* content2 = NULL;
if (xmlBufGetNodeContent(&buf, &node1) == 0) {
    content1 = xmlBufContent(&buf);
}
if (xmlBufGetNodeContent(&buf, &node2) == 0) {
    content2 = xmlBufContent(&buf);
}
if (strcmp(content1, content2) == 0) {
    /* nodes match */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the api calls  xmlBufGetNodeContent and xmlBufContent are any more valid.
As the datatype involved in those calls -  xmlBufPtr are no more available , atleast not on
libxml2 2.7.6
I used a different api call [xmlNodeDump](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeDump) or [xmlNodeGetContent](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeGetContent). hope it helps others with similar question.